# ImageView rotation using slider

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uislider

I am trying to rotate an image using slider..its working well but when i zoom in or zoom out that imageView using Pinch gesture and then try to rotate it using Slider then it  resizes the imageView's frame to its original frame and then rotate it..i Want it to rotate the new imageview after  performing zoom operation...heres my code.

```
//for rotation
- (IBAction)sliderChanged:(id)sender
 {
    imageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(Slider.value * 2*M_PI / Slider.maximumValue);
 }
//for  zoom in zoom out
- (IBAction)handlePinch:(UIPinchGestureRecognizer *)recognizer 
{

    recognizer.view.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(recognizer.view.transform,       recognizer.scale, recognizer.scale);
    recognizer.scale = 1;

}
```

Comment: Hie all..its an old thread though but im stuck on this since few days..i have a uislider that functions for zooming and rotation gesture to rotate the image view the zoom works fine until and unless the rotation is not done but zooming after rotation behaves weird!! Can anyone help me with this i have searched along threads but didnt get any similar to this thread..Kindly help me!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `handlePinch` you correctly modify existing transform, but in `sliderChanged` you create new transform, losing scaling.

Comment: yes isnt there any way  to rotate without loosing previous transforms?

Comment: You will either remember last rotation angle, since `CGAffineTransformRotate` will rotate *by* angle and not *to* angle. Or remember last scale and recreate transform with `CGAffineTransformMakeScale` and then rotate it.

Comment: Hie all..its an old thread though but im stuck on this since few days..i have a uislider that functions for zooming and rotation gesture to rotate the image view the zoom works fine until and unless the rotation is not done but zooming after rotation behaves weird!!
Can anyone help me with this i have searched along threads but didnt get any similar to this thread..Kindly help me!!!

Answer (score 1):

You are not maintaining the scale.  an example of something that works:

```
-(IBAction)zoomIn:(id)sender{
     x += 0.3;
    CGAffineTransform t;
    t=CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(degrees*M_PI/180);
    imageView.transform=CGAffineTransformScale(t, x, x);
 }
```

you are using the recognizer.view.transform in the CGAffineTransformScale.  Try using the imageView.transform

Comment: i have tried using imageView.transform..I guess your code is for zooming after rotation..I am looking for rotation after zooming..Rotating the zoomed imaged...

Comment: Hie all..its an old thread though but im stuck on this since few days..i have a uislider that functions for zooming and rotation gesture to rotate the image view the zoom works fine until and unless the rotation is not done but zooming after rotation behaves weird!! Can anyone help me with this i have searched along threads but didnt get any similar to this thread..Kindly help me!!!